# Check if json file has entries

Tags: python, json

I want to see if my json file has any entries in it.

Currently my json file looks like this:

```
{
}
```

I want to check to see if a user has already added something to the json file (like for e.x `"stackoverflow": "test"`).

With this code I can list all objects in the file

```
    with open("keys.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for obj in data:
            print(obj)
```

Now I wantt to check if the json file is empty or not, I thought to do it so:

```
    with open("keys.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for obj in data:
            if not obj:
                print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + "No sites/TOTP codes have been added yet, add one first.")
```

However sadly this does not work, any ideas?

Comment: "_this does not work_" - explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check is the file is an empty object, you can't, by definition, iterate on it (there is nothing to iterate on)

```
with open("keys.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

if not data:
    print("File is an empty structure") # empty dict or empty list
```

---

To handle the most cases, a list or a dict you could do

```
if not data:
    print("File is an empty structure") # empty dict or empty list

elif isinstance(data, list):
    for obj in data:
        print(obj)

elif isinstance(data, dict):
    for k, val in data.items():
        print(k, "=", val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the size of file - no elements would be say 2 bytes or less...

`os.path.getsize("/path/file.ext")`

Not sure if this is what you're after?